# is there a way to keep actual value of the field in java Pojo?

Tags: java, lombok

Assume I have a model class `Employee`. I would like the keep the actual value of salary  in `initSalary` field during first time load. So that I can reuse the actual salary value wherever it is required.

```
class Employee {
  private int id;
  private double salary;
  private double initsalary;
}
```

Consider this Employee class being used to fetch record from DB. I would like to store the value of salary field in `initsalary` field

Comment: You can implement your own setter for `salary` that stores the current field value to `initsalary` if `initsalary` equals some default value.

Comment: You should add the lombok annotation by the way.

Comment: @f1sh Can you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a constructor that take an `id` and the `salary` and set `initsalary` with `salary`

```
    class Employee {
      private int id;
      private double salary;
      private double initsalary;

      Employee(int id, double salary) {
        this.id = id;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.initsalary = salary;
      }
   }
```